# How to use a Method from a nested class inside the Body of a Method from the first layer class

Tags: java, class, methods, nested

I am Studying Systems-Engineering for just 2 Month so please go easy on me. I am working on a Project with lists, stacks and Binary Trees. The Code I am having trouble with is the one inside of the Binary Tree.

```
public class BinaryIntTree {


public static class Node {
    
    int value;
    
    The left child.

    Node leftChild;
    
    public int getNodeCount(Node node) {
        if(node == null) {return 0;}
        int counter = 0;
        
        if(node.leftChild == null && node.rightChild == null) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            counter += 1;
            if (node.leftChild != null) {
                counter += getNodeCount(node.leftChild);
            }
            if (node.rightChild != null) {
                counter += getNodeCount(node.rightChild);
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
    
    
    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

 public int getNodeCount() {
    return root.getNodeCount(root);
}
```

the second getNodeCount() is in the Main class and I want, that if I use getNodeCount(), that I can't change the Object(root), which is used as the starting point. So I thought id just implement it in the nested Node class and let it be called in the Method from the Main class.

But it throws out a NullPointerException, which should be solved with  if(node == null) {return 0;} but it does not.
Thank you for your help in advance, also please no comment on the Method per se, since I want to solve the recursive method myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getNodeCount` takes a `Node` as an argument, and doesn't use the `Node` instance it's called upon (i.e., the `this`), meaning it should probably be `static`. Once you make it static, you can call it without an instance, and thus avoid the `NullPointerException` you're running into:

```java
public int getNodeCount() {
    return Node.getNodeCount(root);
}
```

Comment: is there a way without making it a Static Method ? 
I tried to refference the Childs with this now but then i don't have a Parameter i can put into getNodeCount() for the rekursiv method